# Accept Testflight Beta invitation without using email?

Tags: ios, email, testflight, beta

Has anyone found a way to accept a TestFlight Beta invite without using the Apple Mail app?

My users don't have personal email associated with their devices.  What I would like to do is provide a method that they copy the link to their device.  One way would be to convert the link in the invite email to a QR code, which they could then scan on their device and use.  However, I haven't been able to figure out how to use the link from QR apps such as ZBar.  They just open the TestFlight Beta App in iTunes or they fail.

The solution I'm looking for won't require users to manually key in a long and complicated url.

Does TestFlight Beta somehow check to see if an email address that matches the invite is configured?

Classic TestFlight was soooo much better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also copy the link and send it to your device using Message.

Comment: Good idea!  Didn't know it could work from Message.  You can only receive messages though from a a Mac you have set up to do this.  Another way might be email-to-SMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the Testflight link (sent in the invite) on your desktop browser, you'll likely see a screen that looks like this:
[image: Typical Invite Screen]

There's a redemption code in there which you can then pass along in the Testflight iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

I had success manually typing the link into Safari on the device but I only needed to do it once.

I am fairly sure each tester receives a unique link so you need to ensure the Apple ID that is logged into the TestFlight app on the device matches the link that is used.

Comment: You technically answered my question, but I'm more interested in a way that doesn't required users to manually key in long and complicated urls into Safari.  I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Sure, just sharing that it is the unique link that is critical so any technique that gets that link onto the iPad should work. I don't know any simple ways but unique QR Codes for each email should work. Or a temp Gmail account, forward the invite and access through safari.

Comment: Assuming that the user has an Apple ID linked to their email address and that ID has been used to login to the TestFlight app on the destination iPad